# Converting CSV records to custom datatype IEnumerable (C#)

Tags: c#, csv, ienumerable

I've got some data in plain CSV format, say:

a1,b1
a2,b2
a3,b3

I've created a class (CsvRecord) which can consume one element each from a single csv line. Using Linq, I've been able to convert the CSV data to an `IEnumerable<CSVRecord>` using this line of code:

```
IEnumerable<CSVRecord> list = csvList.Select(a => new CSVRecord(a.Split(new char[]{','})[0], a.Split(new char[]{','})[1]));
```

This does do what I want but just by looking at it, it doesn't seem like a good way of achieving this. Could you please suggest how could I improve on this?

Comment: The CSV format has some caveats - for example, in a comma-separated file, the values containing commas have to be delimited by quotes, and if they contain quotes as well, these quotes must be doubled. Your code does not handle all these cases. Mr Moose is right, you should using an existing library for this, or you risk running into problems you don't expect.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely do not want to write your own CSV parser (as you've identified) unless you are also prepared to implement the [RFC 4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) standard fully. That is probably not what you want to do. There are so many un-obvious edge cases. Foruntately, implementations already exist.

I would use [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). I've used it for reading and writing on several occasions and it's always been a good library to use in my experience.

Answer (score -1):

There are several good CSVReader libraries around.

A good way to improve is take a look at the code out there and if you want to reinvent the wheel as a learning experience, the use these as examples.

However, if you simply want their functionality, then use a pre-existing library.

Check out;

http://www.csvreader.com/ (costs, but is good. You can even buy the source code if needs be).
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

I'm sure there are plenty more out there also.